# Website loads slow / Chrome Inspect Element Network says Waiting

Tags: asp.net, iframe, google-chrome-devtools

I have a fairly complicated ASP.NET website that has been live for about 4 years.  We moved from our original developers' server over to HostGator about a year and a half ago and I took over the programming.  About a month ago, HostGator's server crashed and they had to migrate everything to what they say is a "newer" server with all the same software.  Now, nearly all of our pages load very slowly (sometimes 15 seconds).  They are trying to blame it on our code, but it loaded fine for years until now and I don't believe I made any changes that could have caused this.

If I open up the developer tools in Chrome and go to "Network" it appears that I have 3-4 pages that are iframed in that are causing the majority of the delay.  If I scroll over these entries, it indicates that nearly all of the time is spent "waiting".  I'm guessing this just means waiting on the server to send the page...

Is there any way to find more details about "waiting"?  Does anyone know why iframes would all of a sudden take so long to load after a hardware move?  I know this is a vague question but I am clueless and HostGator is not very helpful.

Thank you

Comment: IT guys always seem to blame the coders for slowness, and we tend to blame the hardware... Without more information, it is hard to say, but since you know the problem pages, its time for you to start running through and optimizing that code and/or looking for the problem. This part makes me wonder tho: "and I don't believe I made any changes that could have caused this"... small changes CAN do things like this.

Comment: MikeSmithDev, thanks for the comment.  Now that I think about it... there's no way I caused this.  The main site loads slow but I haven't made any changes to it in almost a year... only to a development subdomain (basically a copy of the site).

Comment: Can you clone the systems, then benchmark the clones, and then turn on debugging to find where the timers, counters, etc. are barking?